# Rails 3 - Separate form for 1 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have one model User with Devise gem. I added a new field called budget.

```
Users
id | name | password | ... | budget
```

I have a file `_form_edit.erb.html` which is different from `_form.erb.html`.

`_form_edit` to `update` the profile with budget field.
`_form` to `create` process for devise.

users_controller.erb

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**How to prevent devise gem from logging out when I update budget in my profile?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can imporvise on the way mentioned in the link below about controlling the redirect after a User (Devise model is updated).

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile

Also you might have to ensure that you skip the regular Devise authentication (its a before filter which you can override I think) to ensure you take control of it using your own before filter).

Another probably cleaner but more painful way is to spilt your model into User and (something like) UserInformation, where you can have a one-to-one relationship with User. You can maintain all non auth related information about a User in this model, and treat it like other Models in the system. This approach is better in case 'budget' is not just a one of thing and you have a lot more information in your User Profile.